# Setting Up Geth / Ethminer - Am I Doing This Right?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, cpp-ethereum, ethminer

My apologies if this has been covered elsewhere, but I went through several different guides and sources, both "official" documentation, and whatnot, about how to get started for mining. I feel I have followed the instructions to the best of my ability, but I feel like I am spinning my wheels in the mud here.

I downloaded the following:
Ethereum Wallet (had a link here, can't post more than 2 links without 10 rep?really?)
cpp-ethereum

then, I have been following this guide mainly, but do have others:
http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html#mining

so, this is as far as I seem to be able to get:
I open a cmd window in the folder with geth, and synced to the blockchain, or so I assume. I even created a second account, unsure of how to sync to my original I created when I opened the wallet app, so now I have two:
(had an image here, won't let me post because I have less than 10 rep...really?)

and then I entered `geth --rpc` and that seemed to get me to the point where it was actively syncing to the blockchain.

I then tried `geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain` and I still only get synced.

However, when I try to actually mine, I never seem to be able to get to that point.

I type `geth ethminer -G` and again, I seem to only get blockchain updates.

I then tried `geth --opencl-device X` where "x" is one of 0,1,2...to me this means that if I only have one GPU, it would be 0 right? so I tried `--opencl-device 0`.

Ultimately, no matter the input, this is what I get, for hours on end. I even went to bed and woke up hoping to find mining activity, and just the same thing:
[image: cmd view]

I read on I think a subreddit page, that someone had a similar issue, and just like me, when they tried to open another cmd box simultaneously, they would get a "file is being used" error, and someone responded with "just close that cmd box, and open a new one, and it should work." I did just that, and I still get the same result.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

And ideally, present me with a solution that doesn't involve re-downloading packages from yet another source? Overall I am pretty frustrated right now, and yes, we are early adopters but my goodness, some consistency with the process, etc would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: See the updated section on http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8037/1268

Comment: i recommend you to use parity for mining : https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Mining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use geth to mine, it won't really work.

Use something like [Genoil ethminer 1.1.7](https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum/blob/110/releases/ethminer-0.9.41-genoil-1.1.7.zip)

All you need to do is create an account for yourself (use Mist to do that), then join a mining pool like [ethermine](http://ethermine.org) and you're off and running.

Comment: What do you mean it wont really work ?

Comment: I mean it's functional, but not practical.  Use a GPU-based miner like cpp-ethereum, or Genoil (a fork of cpp-ethereum).  There are others as well, all significantly more performant than geth.

Comment: Thanks @RossPerkins . I am also able to solo mine via  Genoil ethminer?

Comment: @Joshua__c if you want to solo mine, you want to use geth + etherproxy + Genoil ethminer.  You connect them like ethminer -> etherproxy -> geth.  I do not recommend solo mining unless you have a LOT of GPUs, like hundreds of GPUs or more.